# Convert pandas dataframe

Tags: dataframe

I'm learning python and pandas and would like to convert my dataframe like this :

```
    A  B  C
0  11  2  3
1  22  2  4
2  33  2  8
3  44  5  3
4  55  5  4
5  66  5  8
```

Into :

```
    3   4   8
2  11  22  33
5  44  55  66
```

The "B" column is used in index and "C" for columns.

I found nothing on the internet as I don't really know how to describe my problem.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally succeed to do it. For those who are interested :

```
  import copy
  data=data.groupby("C")
  count=0
  for i,j in data:
     a=i
     dataj=j.drop("C", axis=1)
     dataj=dataj.T
     dataj.columns=list(dataj.loc["B"])
     dataj=dataj.drop(["B"])
     dataj.index=[a]
     print(dataj)
     if count==0:
         data_new=copy.deepcopy(dataj)
         count+=1
     else:
         data_new=pd.concat([data_new, dataj], ignore_index=False)
  data=data_new
```

Sorry it's a bit messy ^^

Answer (score 0):

let's say your data frame called df,

```
df.groupby('B')['A'].apply(lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True)).unstack()
```

Comment: df.T will transpose the dataframe but in my case i want that the column "B" become the index and "C" the columns

Comment: I've done data=data.groupby("B") and when printing the program gives me : <pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x00000000179979E8>

Comment: see the results with .head()

Comment: print(data.groupby('B').head()) gives me back data :/

Comment: @AlexJJ sorry for the wrong answer, I just corrected it for you.

Comment: In fact if i replace 0,1,2 in the column "C" by 5,8,4 for exemple, I still get 0,1,2. Is it possible to change that? thanks